# Service Fabric and Application Insights

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights

I am new to service Fabric and trying to integrate my windows service application into service fabric. For logging information, we are planning to use Application Insights. But the events are not logged if i send it through my SF application. At the same time, through a normal console/windows application, I can able to log the message to applicationinsights and can be viewed from there.

Then I tried to create a VM in azure environment, and create SF application there and send the log information to AI and its worked successfully. I copied the same codebase  into my local machine and run it, its not working. I am not sure whether its related to any firewall or proxy settings. Can anyone help on this?

I have used the nuget package to install Microsoft.ApplicationInsights dll in my machine. The version that I used is 2.2.0. And I am using .Net framework 4.6.1

Comment: From the information here it would be hard to say why your local machine isn't able to send events to AI.  Did you let the application run long enough locally for the events to be uploaded (5-10 minutes)?

Comment: Hi. Does it take 5 to 10 minutes for application logs to reach the appinsights logs? On my local machine it takes only 10 seconds.

Answer (score 6):

You could look at [EventFlow](https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow) to help you capture Service Fabric ETW Events from your SF services and send them to Application Insights.

It's easy enough to setup, simply add `Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventFlow.ServiceFabric` NuGet to your Service Fabric service project and [then setup a pipline](https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow#service-fabric-support)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        using (var diagnosticsPipeline = ServiceFabricDiagnosticPipelineFactory.CreatePipeline("MyApplication-MyService-DiagnosticsPipeline"))
        {
            ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync("MyServiceType", ctx => new MyService(ctx)).Wait();

            ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceTypeRegistered(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id, typeof(MyService).Name);

            Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceHostInitializationFailed(e.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

In your `eventflow.config` you can then [setup Application Insights](https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow#application-insights) as an output:

```
{
    "inputs": [
        {
            "type": "EventSource",
            "sources": [
                 { "providerName": "Your-Service-EventSource" }
           ]
        },
    ],
    "filters": [
        {
            "type": "drop",
            "include": "Level == Verbose"
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        // Please update the instrumentationKey.
        {
            "type": "ApplicationInsights",
            "instrumentationKey": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
        }
    ],
    "schemaVersion": "2016-08-11",
    "extensions": []
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your quick reply. I am going to check that one. I have one question. I am directly log the events into the AI using TelemetryClient.TrackTrace method. I didn't use ServiceEventSource for logging into AI. Thanks, Divya

Comment: As long as you use the same AI instrumentation key you should be able to see both your "manually" traced telemetry and traces generated by EventFlow from ETW events sent by the Service Fabric framework (reliable services and actors events, such as methods start/stop and exceptions).

Comment: Still I have the confusion that why the difference in a VM in azure and local machine. I have repeated the same step in both the places. Only diffrence is in VM, it is windows server 2012 and local machine is windows 8.1. The same code is running in both the places.

Comment: I am not using .net core. The eventflow.config file is not generated in my application

Comment: Thats a little strange. You should get one when adding the NuGet package [Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventFlow.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventFlow.Core/) it should add the config file to your project. It's not dependent on you running .NET Core, it works for regular .NET as well. You can add an eventflow.config to your project manually and just copy the boilerplate from the github documentation .

Comment: Not that the config file is placed in the PackageRoot\Config folder of your ASF service.

Comment: Hi, in the production environment its working fine without any code changes. So the problem may be with my local dev environment.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the EventFlow approach suggested by [yoape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42641512/67824) would be Azure Diagnostics (WAD).

[Setup WAD in SF VMSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-how-to-setup-wad)

> When you're running an Azure Service Fabric cluster, it's a good idea
>   to collect the logs from all the nodes in a central location. Having
>   the logs in a central location helps you analyze and troubleshoot
>   issues in your cluster, or issues in the applications and services
>   running in that cluster. One way to upload and collect logs is to use
>   the Windows Azure Diagnostics (WAD) extension, which uploads logs to
>   Azure Storage, and also has the option to send logs to Azure
>   Application Insights or Event Hubs. You can also use an external
>   process to read the events from storage and place them in an analysis
>   platform product, such as OMS Log Analytics or another log-parsing
>   solution.

[Setup AI upload in WAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/azure-diagnostics-configure-application-insights)

> Cloud services, Virtual Machines, Virtual Machine Scale Sets and
>   Service Fabric all use the Azure Diagnostics extension to collect
>   data. Azure diagnostics sends data to Azure Storage tables. However,
>   you can also pipe all or a subset of the data to other locations using
>   Azure Diagnostics extension 1.5 or later. This article describes how
>   to send data from the Azure Diagnostics extension to Application
>   Insights.

The nice thing about it is that it's completely managed by Azure, and you don't need to change anything in your project.

Comment: @CodyGray I added some key excerpts from the articles, hope it's better now.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Dealing with a flag on this answer yesterday and was hesitant to simply delete. Glad I didn't have to.

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt the watchdog Service from Microsoft Samples. The watchdog Service is a generic standalone Service Fabric Stateful Service that will log data into Application Insights.

1. Add the watchdog app and watchdog service into your solution.
2. Add your Azure App ID in the WatchDogService -PackageRoot/Config/ServiceManifest.xml
3. In the service that you need monitored, in the Run Async command, add the following lines (Example is in the Test Stateless Service provided in the link below)

Code:

```
 protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Register the health check and metrics with the watchdog.
        bool healthRegistered = await this.RegisterHealthCheckAsync(cancellationToken);
        bool metricsRegistered = await this.RegisterMetricsAsync(cancellationToken);

        while (true)
        {
            // Report some fake metrics to Service Fabric.
            this.ReportFakeMetrics(cancellationToken);
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), cancellationToken);

            // Check that registration was successful. Could also query the watchdog for additional safety.
            if (false == healthRegistered)
            {
                healthRegistered = await this.RegisterHealthCheckAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
            if (false == metricsRegistered)
            {
                metricsRegistered = await this.RegisterMetricsAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

4. Copy the RegisterHealthCheckAsync, RegisterMetricsAsync and ReportFakeMetrics methods, as is, into your service.cs file.

That should be it! It uses Azure Storage optionally. I did not have to implement that to get the watchdog up and running.

Here is the link : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-watchdog-service

Answer (score 0):

For sending application/service telemetry to Application Insights, I strongly recommend you have a look at [App Insights Service Fabric](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-ServiceFabric). It works great for:

- Sending error and exception info
- Populating the application map with all your services and their dependencies (including database)
- Reporting on app performance metrics, as well as,
- Tracing service call dependencies end-to-end,
- Integrating with native as well as non-native SF applications

One thing however that the above won't solve is providing overall cluster health information - e.g. when/how often nodes go up/down, how much CPU/Memory and disk IO is consumed on individual nodes.

When running in Azure, the above should be fairly simple and I recommend you start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-oms-setup).

Doing this on-premise is not quite as simple. For this you could try MS [EventFlow](https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow), or some of the other solutions already mentioned above.

Personally, I ended up creating a simple/custom [windows service](https://github.com/Adebeer/Service-Fabric-AppInsights-Health-Monitor) that use standard App Insights nuget packages to report the following info:

- [Cluster and Node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-event-generation-operational) ETW events from the Service Fabric Operational ETW channel
- Performance counters (configurable via app insights config file)