# Application Insights and Service Fabric Micro services (stateful and stateless)

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights

I found many questions from several months back on Application Insights and Service Fabric and I'm wondering if there is any new information.

I would really like to get information for APIs (Stateful and state less service) response time, dependency, traces etc. In typical API, enabling and configuring the application insight with tracing and web api application insight,  it shows the server response time, server requests and operation details.
Along with it, it will also have the dependency and tracing information. I would like to get same information for services running on the service fabric. I could add these by adding customize code using nuget like Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventListeners and Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventListeners.Fabric which allows to log the start and end with the custom code.Here are  the links which I referred  -

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2016/10/06/distributed-tracing-in-service-fabric-using-application-insights/

[Application Insights in Service Fabric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348793/application-insights-in-service-fabric)

https://acom-feature-videos-twitter-card.azurewebsites.net/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-diagnostics-application-insights-setup/

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: Maybe this will help you some more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639663/service-fabric-and-application-insights

Comment: Thanks EranG. I am looking more tracking the server response, dependency etc. The approach you mentioned are  for event source, isn't it

Comment: I think it will be really hard to come up with an integrated solution for AI. Take the server response (assuming you're talkin about timings): the communication between services is not defined, it could be remoting, wcf, owin or whatever. service remoting does not provide any mechanism like middleware in owin for example so tracking request timings is really hard without writing it yourself. You could capture the eventsource messages and forward them as traces or requests to AI, that's described in the link @EranG provides.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I am referring  the same functionality which could be achieved in Appservice and application insight with the help of nuget.

Comment: @AzureDev take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348793/application-insights-in-service-fabric/43371886#43371886

Comment: Thanks but I ended up writing the custom wrapper, hoping to have web like plug in for SF as well.